# Coverting String to PHP Associative Array

Tags: php, arrays, string, converters, associative-array

How can i convert this string

```
$str = "array('3'=>'wwm','1'=>'wom')";
```

to real php associative array...

Comment: How do you get such a string in the first place?

Comment: I am sending this string to database ... and now i want to use it after retrieving from database

Comment: Do NOT do that. Use http://ch2.php.net/serialize instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's simple but **REALLY INSECURE**

```
$str = "array('3'=>'www.tension.com','1'=>'www.seomeuo.com','requestedBy'=>'1')";
eval("\$array = $str;");
```

You never should use this approach, there another ways to do it like: `serialize()` and `unserialize()`

Comment: serialization is the better choice

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /home/user/test.php(5) : eval()'d code on line 1

Comment: Fixed, first $ sign should be escaped with \

Comment: Not fixed. Still get: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /home/user/test.php(5) : eval()'d code on line 1 – hek2mgl 11

Comment: Yes, now it's working, after you've added to the `;`. Note that the `;` is essential

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `eval()` function for that:

```
$str = "array('3'=>'wwm','1'=>'wom')";

eval("\$a=$str;");

var_dump($a);
```

However using `eval()` in your code is considered to be risky and you should not use it. Try to use `serialize()`, `unserialize()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

First of all. Do not use eval. It is Evil!
http://af-design.com/blog/2010/10/20/phps-eval-is-evil/

Secondly. The simple solution would not to be using this string but simply to use "serialize" when you put it in the DB and unserialize when you pull it out. You are storing a very unusual format.